# DateTime.ParseExact omitting milliseconds in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to convert a string to Datetime in c#.
String datestring= 2013/03/18 10:54:07.679

1. I tried `DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff",null);`
   The result is {3/18/2013 10:54:07 AM}
2. I tried  `DateTime.TryParseExact(datestring,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out dttt);`
   The result is {3/18/2013 10:54:07 AM}

In both the above cases its ommitting millisecons(679).

How can I convert it to datetime correctly by keeping the milliseconds?

Comment: If you want to see milliseconds then you'll have to format the DateTime that way.  And no, the debugger doesn't.  That's not a real problem of course.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

it's not ommitting you are just checking through debugger and debugger shows it using AM or PM ,it doenot show milliseconds part.

Try This:

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff",null);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

**EDIT:** from your comment `But I need the answer in Datetime instead of string`

You have already the DateTime including `MilliSeconds` just debugger is not showing because
(As mentioned in comment by `Ant P`) Debugger calls the Parameterless overload of `ToString()` method which shows the `DateTime` without MilliSeconds.

Comment: Specifically, the debugger just calls the parameterless `ToString` overload, which formats as shown in the question.

Comment: But I need the answer in Datetime instead of string.

Comment: @user3661657 The `DateTime` *already has* the milliseconds. *Just not the string representation that the debugger shows you.*

Comment: @AntP: Good Point let me update that Debugger calls Parameterless ToString overload.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Overload, not constructor ;)

Comment: @Sudhakar...Thank you so much..You are right..when I saved it to database its showing the milliseconds..Thank you..

Comment: @AntP: my mistake ... Yup :) Edited

Answer (score 4):

You need to be aware that the parse exact string fff will not work when the time contains a 2-digit millisecond.

eg in my case I had 2019-08-19 13:35:06.27 which would not parse
but 2019-08-20 13:35:04.274 would parse correctly.
I presume it would also happen for 1 digit and 0 digit milliseconds too.

It will only work if the milliseconds have trailing zeroes. eg .270

Example:

```
string x = "2019-08-20 13:35:04.27";
DateTime d;

bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: This is as expected. `fff` says 'three digits'. `Exact` means it **has** to be 3 digits.

Answer (score 3):

Use uppercase FFF

DateTime.ParseExact("15.06.2020 15:52:04.9", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).