# DateTime losing Milliseconds

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

I am parsing a date from a file as a string and converting it to `DateTime` so that I can compare it with a previous date. I am losing the milliseconds when I do this which are extremely important as I am missing lines from the file I am parsing.

Example of Date From File I am extracting:   `2014/11/12 10:47:23.571`
`m_LatestProcessDate` after I do ParseExact `12/11/2014 10:47:23`

See below line of code I am using. Any ideas how I get around this?

```
DateTime m_LatestProcessDate = DateTime.ParseExact(m_CurrentDateString,
                                                   "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: How do you detect you lose milliseconds? Did you inspect the `m_LatestProcessDate.Millisecond` property, or just dump the DateTime to somewhere? The default DateTime format doesn't include milliseconds.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788656/datetime-parseexact-omitting-milliseconds-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

CodeCaster already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907812/datetime-losing-milliseconds#comment42365773_26907812) your problem, I wanna add this as an answer if he let's me..

Don't worry! Your milliseconds didn't lost. They are still there. Sounds like you just didn't see them when you try to represent your `m_LatestProcessDate` and that's probably because your *string representation* of your `DateTime` doesn't have milliseconds part.

[image]

For example, if you use [`DateTime.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx) without any parameter, this method uses [`"G"` standard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This specifier formats your `DateTime` as [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) + [`LongTimePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx). And **no culture** have `Millisecond` part on it's `LongTimePattern`.

For example; [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has `HH:mm:ss` format which doesn't represent millisecond part.

You can see your milliseconds of your `m_LatestProcessDate` like;

```
Console.WriteLine(m_LatestProcessDate.ToString("fff")); // prints 571
```