# How to parse a UTC string as DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

Today an API changed and broke this legacy code with the following error:

```
[System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
```

The new date take this form: `2020-01-16T14:29:17.9743131Z0`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = "2020-01-16T14:29:17.9743131Z0";
    Console.WriteLine("dateTime : {0}", result);
    Console.WriteLine("result : {0}", Convert.ToDateTime(result));
}
```

[Try it Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rzHmAb)

Neither [DateTime.Parse's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8) nor [DateTime.ParseExact's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) help me as far as I tried at that point. Lets ask internet.

I searched online and found [How to create a .NET DateTime from ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format). The first solution with `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` but [it failed](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HfOLxL) with the same error. The second solution use `DateTime.ParseExact`, custom formats, and `DateTimeStyles.None`. [18 formats. None works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8z3d77). The third one rely on the flag `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`. It didnt work all the same.

I also check another link ([Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)) without success.

How can I handle this format?

Comment: What does the trailing 0 (`Z0`) mean?

Comment: *Neither `DateTime.Parse` nor `DateTime.ParseExact` help me as far as I tried.* ... and solution posted by you is ... `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: @Selvin I updated the question to reflect the problem. I post this as Q&A because I found the solution while searching and I am looking to help others.

Comment: @SalmanA The 'Z' is a delimiter of the UTC spec. I dont know about the '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string follows the standard with the exception of the last `0`.

The "Z" stands for Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). There should be no number after it, so you can safely ignore that extra 0.

```
var dateStr = "2020-01-16T14:29:17.9743131Z0";

var pos = dateStr.IndexOf('Z');
if (pos != -1 && pos < dateStr.Length - 1)
    dateStr = dateStr.Remove(pos + 1);

var date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
```

Comment: Agreed, the 0 should not be here. I open an issue to remove it. Meanwhile, I use this solution as a fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Searching a bit more would have yield this two links [c# convert datetime object to iso 8601 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788305/c-sharp-convert-datetime-object-to-iso-8601-string) and [How to parse and generate DateTime objects in ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313998/how-to-parse-and-generate-datetime-objects-in-iso-8601-format). They dont fix your problem per se, but they give you more information about those pesky decimal in your format: "fff". You can find it under [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8). We want ["FFFFFFF"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#FFFFF_Specifier) especially to match your input.

[image: screenshot of the doc]

Our format could look like this `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff"` We can [try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TXQY73), but *spoiler* it wont work. We are missing "Z0" at the end. Good news, [we can ignore them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#Literals).

[image]

Final code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = "2020-01-16T14:29:17.9743131Z0";
    Console.WriteLine(result);          

    var format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffffZ0";
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(result, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xcj3qF)

Note that this code will not work if you have less than 7 decimal in your string. At then end, maybe you should rely on `@jgauffin` solution.