# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when using SQL Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, datetime

I am using a date out of a SQL Server database that has the miliseconds on it like the example here "2016-10-07 21:00:29:987" which is held in a hidden field.

This is how the data is recorded, and this is one of the clauses of an update in a database.

When I try and pass this into the database as a parameter I get the "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error when using

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(hfDateLocked.Value.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If I remove the milliseconds off this works fine, but as its in the database with the milliseconds and this is one of the three clauses \ conditions I need to pass it through with this.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Edit 1

```
SqlParameter lockTimParam = new SqlParameter("@LockTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfLockTime.Value.ToString()))
{
    lockTimParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    lockTimParam.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(hfLockTime.Value.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: did you try HH:mm:ss.FFF ?

Comment: Are you storing dates in the database as strings? Do not do that!

Comment: You have a `DateTime` object `hfDateLocked` and you're using `DateTime.Parse` ? This doesn't make any sense.  If you want to format your DateTime object to a specific string format, you can just call `.ToString` and pass the desired format. Check the answer below.

Comment: @Mate using that it gives me the correct string, but kicks the milliseconds off

Comment: @mason no im not storing them in the db as a string, but when the value comes back im assigning it to a hiddent value, how else should I do it

Comment: It's not really ommiting the miliseconds, please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23788730/6248956

Comment: @SimonPrice What is the type of `hfLockTime` ? a `DateTime` ? Then just use `lockTimParam.Value = hfLockTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a type-o in your format string, it does not match the format of the `DateTime` string that is being passed in (just the symbol between seconds and milliseconds).

`.fff` should be `:fff`.

```
var result = System.DateTime.ParseExact("2016-10-07 21:00:29:987", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or if the `DateTime` string is changed to use `.` instead of `:` then this works.

```
var result = System.DateTime.ParseExact("2016-10-07 21:00:29.987", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Either way. The milliseconds in the returned `DateTime` string are segregated by a period (`.`) then use `.fff` in the format string, if its a colon (`:`) then use `:fff` in the format string.