# How do you have different culture DateTimes with SignalR such as 'en-AU' (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, json.net, signalr

I cannot find a way for my SignalR hub to accept DateTime values as 'dd/MM/yyyy'. It is reverting to 'MM/dd/yyyy'.

SignalR in the browser seems to be sending the correct value to the server but then the server must be deserializing it in the wrong way. This also means that values such as '20/01/2017' cause errors and don't work at all.

Am I missing something simple here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Server Side Code**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class PersonHub : Hub
{
    public void SendToServer(Person person)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Server DOB: {person.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")}");
    }
}
```

**Client Side Code**

```
Name: <input id="name" />
DOB: <input id="dob" />
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="save()">Save</button>

<script>
    var hub = $.connection.personHub;
    $.connection.hub.start();
    function save() {
        var person = {
        Name: $('#name').val(),
        DateOfBirth: $('#dob').val()
    }
    hub.server.sendToServer(person);
}
</script>
```

**Examples**

05/01/2017 - Server DOB: 01 May 2017
04/08/2016 - Server DOB: 08 Apr 2016
01/12/2015 - Server DOB: 21 Jan 2015
20/01/2017 - Error Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll {"I":"5","E":"There was an error invoking Hub method 'personhub.SendToServer'."}

Comment: [xkcd: ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)... If you still insist on using locale specific date time format to serialize data please show code you have and values that are serialized/deserialized incorrectly (obviously you are not looking at the value in debugger since it will be duplicate post and you've already searched for similar issues).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not serializing in these formats but the end user will most likely type in their local format. I have been playing with this for about a day and searched a lot if I have duplicated a question please give me the link.

Comment: I'd recommend converting from and to an invariant format on the browser side, as the browser and server might be running in different locales and/or time zones.  `JsonSerializerSettings` has [`DateFormatString`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm) and [`Culture`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Culture.htm), but I'm not sure how those interact with SignalR.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788656/datetime-parseexact-omitting-milliseconds-in-c explains what debugger shows. Since you insist on not providing any code sample it is unlikely anyone will be able to answer the questions. (If you decide to [edit] and add code - make sure to read [MCVE] guidance)

Comment: Send the value as a string and parse it as required in your hub method.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the link but it's not related to my problem. I have edited the question with some example code.